# AngularJS Ng-Repeat - Multiple Custom Filters to Filter Items by JSON Object Properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16368/.

I'm trying to filter items in an ng-repeat list by multiple filters if their JSON properties for the object match a selected option.

So when the 'Unread' filter is selected, items will only be displayed where the 'unread' property of each json object is equal to true, and similarly with the high importance filter.

I also want to be able to combine these two filters, so that the list only displays items with both the unread and high importance properties equal to true when the filters are both selected.

I've got a basic setup in the JSFiddle above where I've used models for the filter checkboxes, but have been looking for a while at a method to implement these filters for the list and have been confused as to how I would do what I need for this scenario.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <label for="filterByAllCheckbox">Filter by All </label>
  <input ng-model="filters.all" ng-change="filterByAll()" type="checkbox" id="filterByAllCheckbox" ng-disabled="filters.all">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="filterByUnreadCheckbox">Filter by Unread </label>
  <input ng-model="filters.unread" ng-change="manageFilters()" type="checkbox" id="filterByUnreadCheckbox">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="filterByHighImportanceCheckbox">Filter by High Importance </label>
  <input ng-model="filters.highImportance" ng-change="manageFilters()" type="checkbox" id="filterByHighImportanceCheckbox">
</div>

<br>

<ul>
  <b>NOTIFICATIONS</b>
  <li ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
    {{notification.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such a functionality using ng-show in `li` item checking for the two conditions (unread and highImportance).

```
<li ng-repeat="notification in notifications" 
    ng-show="(filters.all) 
    || (filters.unread && !notification.read && filters.highImportance && notification.importance == 'High')
    || (!filters.unread && notification.read && filters.highImportance && notification.importance == 'High')
    || (filters.unread && !notification.read && !filters.highImportance && notification.importance != 'High')
    || (!filters.unread && notification.read && !filters.highImportance && notification.importance != 'High')">
  {{notification.title}}
</li>
```

I doubt if this the best way to achieve what you describe though.

**Updated. Implementation of custom filter.**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('notificationFilter', function () {

    return function (array, all, unread, highImportance) {

        var matches = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (all 
                || (!unread && highImportance && array[i].importance == 'High')
                || (unread && !array[i].read && !highImportance)
                || (unread && !array[i].read && highImportance && array[i].importance == 'High')) {
            matches.push(array[i]);
        }
        return matches;
    };

});
```

Then you have to call filter in your controller methods.

```
$scope.manageFilters = function() {
    if ($scope.filters.unread == true || $scope.filters.highImportance == true) {
        $scope.filters.all = false;
    } else {
        $scope.filters.all = true;
    }
    $scope.shownNotifications = $filter('notificationFilter')($scope.notifications, $scope.filters.all, $scope.filters.unread, $scope.filters.highImportance);
}
```

And

```
$scope.filterByAll = function() {
    if ($scope.filters.all == true) {
        $scope.filters.unread = false;
        $scope.filters.highImportance = false;
        $scope.shownNotifications = $filter('notificationFilter')($scope.notifications, $scope.filters.all, $scope.filters.unread, $scope.filters.highImportance);
    }
}
```

And of course change html:

```
<li ng-repeat="notification in shownNotifications">
  {{notification.title}}
</li>
```

Be sure to declare `$filter` in controller definition and to initialize list `shownNotifications`.
You can take a look in updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16369/).
Feel free to optimize - change my sample implementation as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like this but was really looking for a js filter method

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is very close, but when only high importance is selected, it doesn't show any items, whereas it should be showing all that have a true high importance property. It only shows unread high importance notifications when both filters are selected. Looks like the high importance filter is flawed

Comment: You can modify filter if statement accordingly to address your needs. The implementation I did is supplementary, when you check high importance and unread or you check high importance and not unread. If you check high importance, you don't mind for read property?

Comment: I modified my answer and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16370/) in order to address what you describe (if I understand it correctly). Please take a look.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply. I was going to take a look at altering the code to adapt it like this myself, I just thought it was an issue with the code at first. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Please take a look and if you are satisfied with my answer, you can vote up and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look at the fiddle and this is exactly how I needed it to work. Having issues implementing the filter itself into my project though. Console is returning an 'unknown provder' error for 'notificationsFilterFilter', even though it's only been called 'notificationsFilter'... wouldn't happen to know what might cause that, would you?

Comment: I believe it is a mispelling issue, please check that the name of the filter is spelled correctly, both in declaration and in filter call.

Comment: It seems its a problem with including it in the controller. I've tried including it in the app.js file, but whenever I try to run one of the filter operations by checking a checkbox, the console returns the unknown provider error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160180/discussion-between-lzagkaretos-and-nick-cook).